# Pig Scripting - Cast STRING to INT

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Beginner in Pig, Need help

For all NON - AlphaNumeric, Cast the STRING TO INT 
         -  To be handled without passing each field name separately.

Sample data -

```
00013425731998101620140402300032736901  00000000AAA001200X111685V00000000
00283335542006120920131010300030003105  00000000AAA001200X117407 00000000
00000000331998101620140402300033128107  00000000AAA001200X111685 00000000
00003902331999090620140402300032545208  00000000AAA001200X111685 00000000
```

Its a fixedwidth file, mapping details as follow -

```
orderNumber 1   9   
origin      10  10      
Startdate   11  18  
ModDate     19  26  
Identifier  27  36      
Code        37  38  
CodeType    39  40      
Number      41  48  
Num         49  114
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want to handle it without passing details for each field name as there are more than 50 fields. Can you guide something like -  Convert to INT for all NON-alphanumeric

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in thing in Pig that would do this, except maybe a regex.

Answer (score 0):

Either use substr to extract the parts and then cast them or use a regexp. For example for the first two fields:

```
input = load ... as (line:chararray);
a = foreach input generate SUBSTRING(line, 0, 9) as orderNumber:long, SUBSTRING(line, 9, 10) as origin:chararray;
```

This way you should be able to convert each part of the input line into the desired components.

Alternatively you could write a UDF that takes a string as input and does the splitting and returns a bag or tuple.